# Replace "template tag" with string in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Open up the document
read -d '' html <<- EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
    <meta name="...">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
EOF

#Overwrite the old file with a new one
echo "$html" > index.html

# Convert markdown to HTML
`cat README.md | marked --gfm >> index.html`

# Put the converted markdown into the HTML
read -d '' html <<- EOF
  </body>
</html>
EOF

# Save the file
echo "$html" >> index.html
```

But what I'd like is a single write instead Basically, in the first `EOF` i'd have the `</html></body>` too, and in between the `<body>` tags I'd have like `{{CONTENT}}` to be replaced with `cat README.md | marked --gfm` like:

```
read -d '' html <<- EOF
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <meta name="...">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
      {{CONTENT}}
      </body>
    </html>
    EOF
```

I tried over and over with the `sed` command, but I think I'm doing something wrong and I read there's issues when the file contents to search thru have slashes in it. How could I implement the `sed` command here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this using a single call to `cat`, using command substitution to insert the read-me in the middle:

```
cat << EOF > index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
    <meta name="...">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  $(marked --gfm < README.md)
  </body>
</html>
EOF
```

---

Another option might be to use `printf`, replacing the {{CONTENT}} placeholder with a simple format string.

```
read -d '' -r template <<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<meta name="...">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
%s
</body>
</html>
EOF

printf "$template" "$(marked --gfm < README.md)"
```

Comment: While this would work, it isn't scalable since moving the HTML template outside the script will cause it to not work.

Comment: Right; I knew I must be missing something when I removed the need for the `{{CONTENT}}` placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't.

```
md="$(marked --gfm <README.md)"
> index.html
while read html
do
  echo "${html/{{CONTENT}}/$md}" >> index.html
done <<- EOF
```

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <meta name="...">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
      {{CONTENT}}
      </body>
    </html>
    EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<body>/!b;n;s/.*/&/e' - <<\EOF > index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
    <meta name="...">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  marked --gfm < README.md
  </body>
</html>
EOF
```